# Why is my caption centered?

Tags: floats

I've got multiple Figures in a Scientific paper but the caption of only one of them is centered. I'm a complete n00b in LaTeX, but to me the formatting looks completely identical to the other figures. Does anyone know why the caption of the first example is centered?

Here is the Figure where the caption is centered (undesired):

[image]

```
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------- % |
                        %       ╔═══╦═══════════════════╗                   % |
                        %       ║ F ║  CLM III - Setup  ║                   % |
\begin{figure} [!htb]   %       ╚═══╩═══════════════════╝                   % |
 \centering                                                                 % |
 \includegraphics[scale=0.38]{../Abbildungen/CLMIII-Setup.jpg}              % |
                                                                            % |
 \caption[Setup CLM III während der Dialyse]                                % |
         {Setup CLM III während der Dialyse}                                % |
 \label{fig:CLMIII-Setup.jpg}                                               % |
\end{figure}                                                                % |
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------- % |`
```

And this is one of the figures with left-aligned caption (that's how I want the caption to be, result can be viewed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwXsi.png)):

```
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------- % |
                        %       ╔═══╦═════════════════════════╗             % |
                        %       ║ F ║  Hb-Absorptionsspektra  ║             % |
\begin{figure} [!htb]   %       ╚═══╩═════════════════════════╝             % |
 \centering                                                                 % |
 \includegraphics[scale=1]{../Abbildungen/Hb-Absorption(A).png}             % |
                                                                            % |
 \caption[Absorptionsspektra von Oxy- und Desoxyhämoglobin]                 % |
         {Absorption von Oxy- und Desoxyhämoglobin                          % |
          \newline Markierung: Isosbestischer Punkt bei 805\,nm}            % |
 \label{fig:Hb-Absorption(A).png}                                           % |
\end{figure}                                                                % |
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------- % |`
```

I'm using TexMaker 4.5 with MikTex on a Windows 8.1 64bit machine.

*edit:*
Document class is

`\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, listof=totocnumbered, listof = leveldown, bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrreprt}`

That's my very first submission so please be patient and feel free to ask for any further information :)

---

**edit** Thanks everyone for your effort :)

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Which class are you using? Some classes use centred captions unless they are long enough to fill the line.

Comment: this one:

`\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, listof=totocnumbered, listof = leveldown, bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrreprt}`

Comment: with many document classes, if a caption is only one line long, it will be centered, while multiple-line captions are set in paragraph form.  in the link you give, the caption is indeed a short one, so (if you are using one of the described document classes) this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly the case. My first example is the only caption in the whole document without a `\newline` in it - hence the centering.

Comment: i've taken the liberty of bringing the image into the question, so that it doesn't vanish if the link goes away.  when you've accumulated enough rep, you'll be able to do this yourself.

Comment: ehrm.. I don't want to sound impolite, but I chose imgur for the reason that I can delete the screenshots of my document if I have to for any reason. Rehosting my images on a server where I don't have the power to delete them makes me somewhat uncomfortable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [campa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/82917/campa) and [barbara beeton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/579/barbara-beeton) mentioned - the caption in my first example is fitting in one single line and that's why it's automatically centered. Thanks a lot!

edit: see [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%C3%B8rn-t)'s comment to this answer for how to left-align all captions.

Comment: in this particular case, the caption is so narrow, as is the picture, that it is likely to look quite peculiar if it is shifted left to start where the longer captions do.  i'd recommend adding some text to make it wider, if you are determined to shift it left.

Comment: Add `captions=nooneline` to the class options (e.g. after `bibliography=totocnumbered`).